# multiple circles on a css background

Tags: css

Is there a way in css to create multiple circles of different sizes and at different positions on one div elements background ? 
I have a circle currently in a pseudo element but thats not enough so I thought maybe it can be done using background css.

I don't want to add extra divs so trying to get it to work on one div.

Comment: if you want to add multiple circles in one div than you can use canvas and draw multiple circles on it.

Comment: Give us your code, and let us know which `div` you want to work on so that we can help.

Comment: do you need multiple circles on a single div??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use `radial-gradient` and you can have any number of circles:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,yellow 32%,yellow 90% ,purple 93%, purple 96%,transparent) left center/60px 60px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,yellow 96%,transparent) bottom left/80px 80px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,green  96%,transparent) top right/80px 80px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,blue   96%,transparent) 100px 50px/100px 100px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,red    96%,transparent) top left/40px 40px;
    /* the circle                                          position / size */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `box-shadows` with several colours on a rounded div. They need to be seperated by a comma:

```css
#circles {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 100px 2px 0 0 #f8ff00,
              200px 2px 0 0 #009901,
              300px 4px 0 0 #3531ff;
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
}
```

```html
<div id="circles"></div>
```

with several colours on a rounded div. They need to be seperated by a comma: